# My Philips CRT 19" 109p has all gone white, is the Tube dead?

Tags: troubleshooting, display, crt

I have a Philips Brilliance 109 p4 which I love very much.
It was working great for the last 7-8 years I believe.

Today when I started it, the screen is displayed all white. it ain't a computer problem, I've tried to connect the screen to my laptop.

Experts, what is your diagnosis?

EDIT: Got my self a new Samsung T260HD. Hope it will serve at least good as the old one.
Thanks a lot.

Ariel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very few places still repair monitors. Most will charge a fee diagnose the issue. If you are really comfortable with electronics, have some test equipment, and a set of schematics, you might be able to find the issue.

A more realistic proposal would be to replace your CRT with a LCD. They use less power, have better resolution, take up less space, and are easier to read.

Comment: Less power: yes.  Better resolution: not necessarily.  Less space: yes.  Easier to read: arguable.

Comment: Most new LCDs have excellent resolutions, even the least expensive of them. As for readability for me this a combination of contrast and flatness. Again today's LCD screen have very high contrast and they are flat. Even the more expensive "flat" CRTs had a bit of curvature that made glare an issue. Finally you can simply afford a much larger LCD for the same money as a medium size CRT. Of course this is my opinion, others will have their own opinions.

Answer (score 1):

It does sound more like an electronics issue than a tube issue.  For it to be all white the electron beam must be hitting every bit of the screen so the emitter is ok and the magnets that control the beam are ok.  I don't know how economical/possible it is to repair CRTs these days but if I guess if you can find someone who does electronics repairs they could at least have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you've checked the VGA cable for damage, just in case.

If your CRT has a problem, you have zero chance of fixing it yourself. The repair will likely cost close to how much a new CRT would cost you, you'll be without a screen for a while and at the end you'll still have a 7-8 year old monitor. It's time to look for a new one. In fact think of it as an opportunity to upgrade to a brand new tft. You can easily find one at 19" and above in the 100-150 euro range.